# Retrieve data from SP inside of From

Tags: stored-procedures, sql-server-2012

I would like to use [sp_Test] to retrieve the data from the syntax code "FROM" but it does not work. Do you know how to solve it?

Thanks!

[image]

```
create table datatable (id int,
                        name varchar(100),
                        email varchar(10),
                        phone varchar(10),
                        cellphone varchar(10),
                        none varchar(10)                        
                       );

insert into datatable values
  (1, 'productname', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A'), 
  (2, 'cost', '20', 'A', 'A', 'A'),
  (3, 'active', 'Y', 'A', 'A', 'A');

insert into datatable values
  (4, 'productname', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A'), 
  (5, 'cost', '20', 'A', 'A', 'A'),
  (6, 'active', 'Y', 'A', 'A', 'A');


insert into datatable values
  (7, 'productname', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A'), 
  (8, 'cost', '20', 'A', 'A', 'A'),
  (9, 'active', 'Y', 'A', 'A', 'A');


CREATE PROCEDURE [sp_Test]
as
begin
    set nocount on

    SELECT a.name, a.email, a.phone
    FROM datatable a 

end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you should never name your stored procedure with `sp_` prefix. It is very bad habit and can collide with system stored procedures.

Second you cannot simply use `SELECT FROM EXEC`, but you can create temporary table/variable to hold result and query it like:

```
DECLARE @t AS TABLE ( name varchar(100),
                      email varchar(10),
                      phone varchar(10));

INSERT INTO @t
EXEC [dbo].[sp_Test];

SELECT *
FROM @t;
```

<kbd>**[`SqlFiddleDemo`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/58b17/2/0)**</kbd>

There is also workaround using loopback linked server and `OPENQUERY`:

```
SELECT * 
FROM OPENQUERY(LOCALSERVER, 'EXEC [sp_Test]');
```

I strongly recommend to read:

- [`How to Share Data between Stored Procedures`](http://www.sommarskog.se/share_data.html)
- [`Why is selecting from stored procedure not supported in relational databases?`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33833353/5070879).