# 'syntax error at or near "VARCHAR"' in DECLARE section when trying to create function

Tags: sql, postgresql, plpgsql, user-defined-functions, stored-functions

I've created the following stored procedure which should return all the location names that had an intersection with polygon group (without distinct... intersection with 3 polygons => 3 names)

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_name_without_distinct_by_polygon_group(start_time TIMESTAMP,
                                                                      end_time TIMESTAMP,
                                                                      polygon_group_id INTEGER)
RETURNS TABLE(name_name_name_name VARCHAR(12)) AS $$
DECLARE
  name VARCHAR(12);
  poly_id INTEGER;
BEGIN
  FOR poly_id IN (SELECT polygon_id 
                  FROM polygon_group_members 
                  WHERE group_id = poly_id)
    LOOP
      FOR name IN (SELECT DISTINCT name
                   FROM location, polygons
                   WHERE location.timestamp BETWEEN start_time AND end_time
                        AND poly_id = polygons.id
                        AND st_intersects(location.polygon, polygons.polygon))
      LOOP
        RETURN NEXT name;
      END LOOP;
  END LOOP;
  RETURN;
END;

$$ LANGUAGE SQL;
```

When I tried to create this function I got the following error:

> [42601] ERROR: syntax error at or near "VARCHAR" Position: 356

Based on PostgreSQL [declaration documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/plpgsql-declarations.html) it seems OK ...

What I've tried so far:

- I changed `name VARCHAR(12);` to `name location.mac%TYPE`
- I changed `name VARCHAR(12);` to `name RECORD`
- I changed the scope of the declaration then I got the same error on `poly_id INTEGER;`
- I changed the `LANGUAGE SQL` to `postgressql`
- I googled it and according to any example/problem I found this procedure should work.

Comment: [There are no "stored procedures" in Postgres, just functions](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33896307/939860). And are you linking to Postgres 9.1 documentation because that's your actual version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your posed answer still has a couple of problems. And you can very well use `RETURNS TABLE()`. Compare:

- [plpgsql error "RETURN NEXT cannot have a parameter in function with OUT parameters" in table-returning function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14039720/plpgsql-error-return-next-cannot-have-a-parameter-in-function-with-out-paramete/14039866#14039866):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_name_without_distinct_by_polygon_group(start_time timestamp,
                                                                      end_time timestamp,
                                                                      polygon_group_id int)
  RETURNS TABLE(name_name_name_name VARCHAR(12)) AS
$func$
DECLARE
   name VARCHAR(12);  -- possible naming conflict!
   poly_id int;
BEGIN
   FOR poly_id IN  --  no parentheses needed
      SELECT polygon_id
      FROM   polygon_group_members 
      WHERE  group_id = poly_id  -- I suspect you really want polygon_group_id here
   LOOP
      FOR name_name_name_name IN  -- assign directly
         SELECT DISTINCT name  -- l.name or p.name??
         FROM   polygons p
         JOIN   location l ON st_intersects(l.polygon, p.polygon)
         WHERE  p.id = poly_id
         AND    l.timestamp BETWEEN start_time AND end_time
      LOOP
        RETURN NEXT;  -- already assigned
      END LOOP;
   END LOOP;
   RETURN;
END
$func$  LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Be aware of possible naming conflicts. All declared variable and parameters (including fields in the `RETURNS TABLE()` clause are visible in SQL queries inside the body of a plpgsql or SQL function. A widespread convention would be to prepend variable names with `_` and table-qualify all columns in queries. See earlier answer from today:

- [Check for integer in string array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34277798/check-for-integer-in-string-array/34288654#34288654)

The whole function could probably be replaced with a single `SELECT` statement.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need PL/pgSQL for this. The loops are unnecessary and will make everything very slow.

As far as I can tell this should do it:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_name_without_distinct_by_polygon_group(start_time TIMESTAMP,
                                                                      end_time TIMESTAMP,
                                                                      polygon_group_id INTEGER)
   RETURNS TABLE(name_name_name_name VARCHAR(12)) 
AS 
$$
  SELECT DISTINCT name
  FROM location, polygons
  WHERE location.timestamp BETWEEN start_time AND end_time
    AND poly_id IN (SELECT polygon_id  FROM polygon_group_members WHERE group_id = polygon_group_id)
    AND st_intersects(location.polygon, polygons.polygon));
$$ 
LANGUAGE SQL;
```

I also think that the condition `WHERE group_id = poly_id` is wrong as you are using the variable that should store the result in the `where` clause. I think you meant to use `WHERE group_id = polygon_group_id` (I changed that in the above code)

---

When using `language sql` you cannot use procedural code like `begin ... end` or declare variables.

The error `ERROR: syntax error at or near "VARCHAR" Position: 356` is caused by using `language sql` but using PL/pgSQL inside the function body. If you change `language sql` to `language plpgsql` in your definition, it should work (but again that solution having two nested loops is not very efficient).

Comment: You are right about the `LANGUAGE plpgsql` (in the comment you've deleted...) then I got a new error which I am working on it... However as I wrote in the question there is no distinct on names (BTW location name is not a primary key). the first loop gives me all the polygons in the group. the second loop gives me all the <distinct> names that are intersect with the polygon. the procedure will return all the names without distinct so if a location has intersection with 3 polygons(over the time, the locations are not fixed) I'll have 3 names in the result...

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to @a_horse_with_no_name's comment which point me out that `$$ LANGUAGE SQL` should be `$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql` I found the solution.
After I changed to `$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql` I got a new error about missing `OUT PARAMETER`, but `OUT PARAMETER` is not allowed with `RETURN NEXT` so I had to return `SETOF` instead of `TABLE`:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_name_without_distinct_by_polygon_group(start_time TIMESTAMP,
                                                                      end_time TIMESTAMP,
                                                                      polygon_group_id INTEGER)
RETURNS SETOF VARCHAR(12) AS $$
DECLARE
  name VARCHAR(12);
  poly_id INTEGER;
BEGIN
  FOR poly_id IN (SELECT polygon_id 
                  FROM polygon_group_members 
                  WHERE group_id = poly_id)
    LOOP
      FOR name IN (SELECT DISTINCT name
                   FROM location, polygons
                   WHERE location.timestamp BETWEEN start_time AND end_time
                        AND poly_id = polygons.id
                        AND st_intersects(location.polygon, polygons.polygon))
      LOOP
        RETURN NEXT name;
      END LOOP;
  END LOOP;
  RETURN;
END;

$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Comment: If a_horse's answer was useful to you like you state, consider actually voting for it - like the tooltip suggests "This answer is useful".

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter actually I vote up for his comment. he had a comment on the question which was deleted... his answer was not helpful at all... however your answer is better then my solution(+1 and accept). I just waited to test it....