# Execute a rollback, after running a procedure

Tags: java, postgresql, unit-testing, stored-procedures, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have a problem in creating an unit test to a query. In the Java method, it looks like this:

```
public String method () {
    StringBuilder query = new StringBuilder();
    query.append(" BEGIN  ");
    query.append(" <stored procedure name> ;");
    query.append(" END; " );
    return query.toString(); }
```

In test methods, it must do a rollback transaction. For a classic insert / delete / update, they are added in a batch with start transaction / rollback. But I am not sure if it works for stored procedures, especially if they are contained by "begin" / "end". I need to know the same answer for PostgreSQL.

Comment: You cannot "rollback" `StringBuilder`. It looks like you have deep misunderstanding of transactional model.

Comment: The method returns the String value of the StringBuilder. And the Statement object is made with this string.

Answer (score 0):

For starters, there are no stored procedures in Postgres. Only functions, which do almost, but not quite, the same. A [`DO` statement](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-do.html) or a prepared statement might work for you, too.

In particular, functions are always atomic and run inside a transaction. Either within the outer transaction from where they are called, or in a transaction of their own.

And **yes**, functions can be rolled back just like any other SQL command. Some commands that cannot be rolled back can also not be nested in an outer transaction (like `CREATE DATABASE`), and therefore cannot be used inside a function either.

```
BEGIN;
-- do something else
SELECT myfunc();
-- do something else
ROLLBACK;  -- everything back to the start (well, almost everything)
```

Related:

- [Can PostgreSQL perform a join between two SQL Server stored procedures?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33895894/can-postgresql-perform-a-join-between-two-sql-server-stored-procedures/33896307#33896307)
- [Do stored procedures run in database transaction in Postgres?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28250376/do-stored-procedures-run-in-database-transaction-in-postgres/28251922#28251922)
- [Can I dry run/sandbox sql commands?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22748190/can-i-dry-run-sandbox-sql-commands/22748516#22748516)
- [Split given string and prepare case statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28018991/split-given-string-and-prepare-case-statement/28220532#28220532)

Comment: I need the syntax for Java, to run them as statements, with rollback transaction. One of the problems is if in Oracle, if I put: "begin <procedure> end; rollback; ", the updates are commited. I want to know if it is possible for unit test to run this as a rollback transaction, without delete "begin" and "end".

Comment: @CatalinVladu: `ROLLBACK` only makes sense after `BEGIN` to start a transaction. And yes, functions are rolled back like any other SQL command.

Comment: I know the functions / stored procedures can rolled back. The problem is with "begin / end". I put in SQL Developer "begin insert < anything > ; end;" and the transaction was committed. This is the reason for I asked how to put the block containing "begin / end" in a rollback transaction.

Comment: @CatalinVladu: Not sure what you are asking. There are the key words `BEGIN` and `END` in the body of a plpgsql function. But the function body is a quoted ***string*** and your client should be able to detect that. Maybe your client does not does not understand dollar-quoting? Like in this case? http://stackoverflow.com/q/22747225/939860

Comment: Update: Postgres supports stored procedures since version 11.