# Using procedure in Oracle select * from construction

Tags: oracle

I have an Oracle procedure that executes select statement and returns the result.

I need to use that result in another select statement. Is it possible to do this?

This does not work:

```
SELECT * FROM myprocedure(parameter);
```

Comment: [Why is selecting from stored procedure not supported in relational databases](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33833353/5070879)

Comment: A procedure doesn't *return* anything, do you really have a function, and if so what does it return - a (pipelined) collection, a ref cursor, something else? Or is it a procedure with an our parameter?

Comment: In addition, check this to see how to do it : [Creating a function to return a table](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2829880/create-an-oracle-function-that-returns-a-table)

Comment: Yes, it is an our parameter, so called SYS_REFCURSOR.